# What is the symmetry of a Hamiltonian?

Tags: symmetry, definition, hamiltonian

Recently while I was reading a paper on [integrability of  Rabi model](https://arxiv.org/abs/1103.2461) by D Braak. In this paper there is a discussion about the symmetry of a model and that in the case of the Rabi model it is $\mathbb{Z}_{2}$.

Given a Hamiltonian, how can one find the symmetry of the model?

Comment: When you took quantum mechanics, did you learn about the rotational symmetry of the Hamiltonian for the hydrogen atom?

Comment: You can find a general discussion of symmetry in quantum mechanics at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetry_in_quantum_mechanics.

Comment: The symmetry of a Hamiltonian is not necessarily obvious, and I do not know of an algorithm for finding the maximal symmetry of a Hamiltonian. For example, the symmetry of a hydrogen atom Hamiltonian is actually SO(4), a bigger symmetry group than the obvious SO(3)!

Comment: I am sorry, but couldn't get an understanding of the same. I tried to look into one of our reference texts by JJ Sakurai and didn't find a discussion of this there. could you direct me to some any reading?

Comment: Does Section 4.1 of http://jultika.oulu.fi/files/nbnfioulu-201512082290.pdf help you?

Comment: For a more general introduction, this may help (like some other QM text books): https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-662-04750-7_13